# Question about Poincare Duality and Homology of a Cylinder.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am reading [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307349). I have some questions about Poincare duality and homology of a cylinder. On page 9, example 2.6.

> Let $X = \mathbb{R} \times S^1$ be a cylinder and $Y = X/(0 \times S^1 )$, where the circle at the origin is identified to a single point $p_0$. It is said that
>
> $H_0(X)=0$, $H_1(X) = \mathbb{C}$, $H_2(X) = \mathbb{C}$ and
>   $H_0^c(X)=\mathbb{C}$, $H_1^c(X) = \mathbb{C}$, $H_2^c(X) = 0$.
>
> $H_0(Y)=0$, $H_1(Y) = \mathbb{C}$, $H_2(Y) = \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$ and $H_0^c(Y)=\mathbb{C}$, $H_1^c(Y) = 0$, $H_2^c(Y) = 0$.

How to computes these homologies? Why does Poincare duality fail for $Y$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Poincaré duality only holds for manifolds, and $Y$ is not a manifold since it has a singularity at $p_0$.

Comment: Also, I'm not quite sure what to make of this. $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, so its homology groups should coincide. $Y$ is contractible, so it should have trivial homology.

Comment: @William: for whatever reason, the author is using $H_{\bullet}(X)$ to denote Borel-Moore homology and $H_{\bullet}^c(X)$ to denote ordinary homology.

Comment: could you help this too https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093093/reduced-homology-group-h-ks4-n4-mathbb-z-h4-ks4-n4-mathbb-z-h