# Reduced homology group $H_k(S^4 - N^4, \mathbb Z)=H^{4-k}(S^4 - N^4,\mathbb Z)=H_{k-1}(N^4, \mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z^2$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, surgery-theory

Let $N^4$ be a 4-dimensional $D^2 \times T^2 = D^2 \times S^1 \times S^1$.

(let us denote $\tilde H$ as the reduced homology or homology group)

---

I know that
$$
\tilde H_0(N^4,\mathbb{Z})=0,
$$
$$
H_1(N^4,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z^2,
$$
$$
H_2(N^4,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z,
$$
$$
H_3(N^4,\mathbb Z)=0
$$

---

Am I correct that:
$$
\tilde H_0(S^4 - N^4,\mathbb Z)=0,
$$
$$
H_1(S^4 - N^4, \mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z,
$$
$$
H_2(S^4 - N^4,\mathbb Z)=H^2(S^4 - N^4,\mathbb Z)=H_1(N^4,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z^2,
$$
$$
H_3(S^4 - N^4,\mathbb Z)=0,
$$

---

However, I obtained that

$$
H_1(S^4 - N^4,\mathbb  Z)=H^3(S^4 - N^4,\mathbb  Z)= \tilde H_0(N^4, \mathbb  Z)=0
$$ via Alexander
duality and Poincare duality.

$$
H_3(S^4 - N^4,\mathbb  Z)=H^1(S^4 - N^4,\mathbb  Z)= H_2(N^4, \mathbb  Z)=\mathbb  Z$$ 
via Alexander duality
and Poincare duality.

> Something is wrong? Could you correct my mistakes? Which part leads to the contradiction of my results?

Thank you!

Comment: Poincare duality only works on closed manifolds.

Comment: So how should I derive the above?

Comment: Have you looked at Hatcher's Corollary 3.45 on pg 255 of *Algebraic Toplogy*? It is the statement of Alexander duality.